# How to resolve variable null in retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

The app crash when the variable address or mobile number is null, I use retrofit.

```
private void loadData(String token) {
    mAPIService.getUser(token).enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                mEmailEdit.setText(response.body().getEmail());
                mAdresseEdit.setText(response.body().getAdresse());
                mtelephoneEdit.setText(response.body().getTelephone());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: initialize your model string with ""

Comment: share you logcat when app crash .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 mEmailEdit.setText((response.body().getEmail() != null) ? response.body().getEmail() :"");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MVP architecture for your project, then make sure to put a null check for your view before assigning any value to any variable. For eg.

```
if view != null {
                mEmailEdit.setText(response.body().getEmail());
                mAdresseEdit.setText(response.body().getAdresse());
                mtelephoneEdit.setText(response.body().getTelephone());
}
```

Otherwise, the standard null check for variables will work.